# Update current version on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a python (Django) application on Amazon AWS using Elastic Beanstalk.

It's all ok, and my server is ok with my last application version.
Now I have to update a file into my application so I followed this steps:

- I downloaded last app version from Application Versions section. I download the corresponding file zip.
- I edited my file from this version and I created  a new file zip (this result file zip is the same of the original with my file edited).
- When I upload and deploy this new version of file zip I obtain this error:

> ERROR Your WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist.

Please note that I have not changed the files in the hidden directory .ebextensions and this directory is present in the new zip file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because an error occurs when it try to run deploy script with the new zip file.

You can see that error in **eb-activity logs** and fixed it and deploy it again I think this problem will be solved.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html